# 404 after adding spring security filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

After adding security config to my microservice I'm getting 404 error for all requests. The request itself remains the same as before security configs. I'm entering AuthenticationFilter and getting 404 before entering the controllers method. The controller is annotated with a @RestController.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
    prePostEnabled = true,
    securedEnabled = true,
    jsr250Enabled = true)
public class HttpSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements     WebMvcConfigurer {


@Autowired
private AdminAuthClient adminAuthClient;

@Autowired
private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .antMatcher("/admin/**")
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(adminAuthClient, myUserDetailsService),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: On which `URL` you get 404 not found

Comment: GET localhost:8080/v1/admin/items

Comment: does `v1` is context path?

Comment: yep. Even if I delete it from context path and remove from request - same 404 error

Comment: What does your custom filter do?